# lag/lead entire dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lag, lead

I am having a very hard time leading or lagging an entire dataframe. What I am able to do is shifting individual columns with the following attempts but not the whole thing:

```
require('DataCombine')
df_l <- slide(df, Var = var1, slideBy = -1)
```

using colnames(x_ret_mon) as Var does not work, I am told the variable names are not found in the dataframe.

This attempt shifts the columns right but not down:

```
 df_l<- dplyr::lag(df)
```

This only creates new variables for the lagged variables but then I do not know how to effectively delete the old non lagged values:

```
 df_l<-shift(df, n=1L, fill=NA, type=c("lead"), give.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `dplyr::mutate_all` to apply lags or leads to all columns.

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30)
dplyr::mutate_all(df, lag)
    a  b
1  NA NA
2   1 21
3   2 22
4   3 23
5   4 24
6   5 25
7   6 26
8   7 27
9   8 28
10  9 29
```

Comment: There seems to be a warning about usage of the function funs():          
Warning message:
funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

 # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
This warning is displayed once per session.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point in lagging *all* columns in a `data.frame`. Wouldn't that just correspond to `rbind`ing an `NA` row to your original `data.frame` (minus its last row)?

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 21:30)
rbind(NA, df[-nrow(df), ]);
#    a  b
#1  NA NA
#2   1 21
#3   2 22
#4   3 23
#5   4 24
#6   5 25
#7   6 26
#8   7 27
#9   8 28
#10  9 29
```

And similarly for leading all columns.

Comment: Yes it would correspond to that, but I did not think of this solution. Why is it so uncommon to lag all columns in a dataframe? I using this for a regression and would like to lag all regressors. This works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: No problem @NiccolaTartaglia; glad it helped. I'm still not clear on why you'd want to do that. Just use all predictor values minus the first row in your model, if that's what you need. I don't think this has anything to do with "lagging" values.

Comment: or `rbind(NA, head(df,-1))`

Comment: @Maurits: what you are suggesting absolutely works for me, I just did not think of that simple solution. And how would have described my problem other than calling it 'lagging' values? I had to describe my goal somehow otherwise no one would have understood what I am trying to accomplish, right?

Comment: No worries @NiccolaTartaglia & fair enough. Glad you got there:-)

Comment: Yep, took me long enough. Thanks for the help Maurits and everyone else!

Answer (score 2):

A couple more options

```
data.frame(lapply(df, lag))

require(purrr)
map_df(df, lag)
```

If your data is a `data.table` you can do

```
require(data.table)
as.data.table(shift(df))
```

Or, if you're overwriting `df`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, lag) # Thanks Moody
require(magrittr)
df %<>% map_df(lag)
```

Comment: or `df[] <- lapply(df, lag)` if it's acceptable to overwrite the object